# Why is my fallback to CSS Grid layout not working?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

I have to change my css-grid into a table-based CSS layout. As singles both responsive CSS would work fine, but combining them to a kind of safe-team seems too difficult for me.

Can anyone please check what I missed at "@supports"? I tried to change the wrappers / overwrite the grid-rules with the rules of my fallback, but the result is not yet what I want.

```css
<style type="text/css">

html {box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper-of-wrapper {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column nowrap;
    justify-content: center;
}


.wrapper {
    height: auto;
    display: grid;
    -ms-grid;
    -ms-grid-columns: 16% 16% 16%;
    -ms-grid-rows: 10% 10% 10%;
    flex: 0;
    grid-column-gap: 7px;
    grid-row-gap: 7px;
    grid-template-columns: 16% 16% 16%;
    justify-content: center; /*horizontal*/
    align-content: center; /*vertical*/
    grid-auto-flow: row dense;
    }


.box
   {justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background: grey;
      }


img {max-width: 90%;
      height: auto;
      margin: 5px;
              }


.a {grid-column: 1 / span 2;
    grid-row: 1 / span 2; border: 5px solid red;}
.b {grid-column: 3; grid-row: 1}
.c {grid-column: 3; grid-row: 2}
.d {grid-column: 1; grid-row: 3}
.e {grid-column: 2; grid-row: 3}
.f {grid-column: 3; grid-row: 3}



@media only screen and (max-width: 600px)
{/*some definitions*/ }


@supports not (display: grid) {
.wrapper-of-wrapper {
    width: 100% !important;
    height: 100% !important;
    margin: 0 !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
    display: table !important;
    position: relative !important;
    table-layout: fixed !important;
    border: 2px solid blue;
    }


.a  {display: table-cell !important;
      position: relative !important;
      vertical-align: middle!important;
      max-width: 80% !important;
      max-height: auto !important;
      margin: auto !important;
      border: 2px solid red;
    }


#A {position: relative !important;
      vertical-align: middle !important;
      max-width: 30% !important;
      border: 0px solid;
      margin: 8px !important;
      max-width: 600px !important;
      max-height: 400px !important;
      width: 65% !important;
      height: auto !important;
       }


.b {display: none;}

.c {display: none;}

.d {display: none;}

.e {display: none;}

.f {display: none;}





@media only screen and (max-width: 600px)
{/*some definitions*/ }

  }

</style>
```

```html
<body>
  
<!-- - - - - - - - - - -->

<div class="wrapper-of-wrapper">
<div class="wrapper">


<div class="box a" id="A">
<img style="border 2px solid red" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x200">
</div>

<div class="box b" id="B">
<img src="http://via.placeholder.com/170x100">
</div>

<div class="box c" id="C">
<img src="http://via.placeholder.com/170x100">
</div>

<div class="box d" id="D">
<img src="http://via.placeholder.com/170x100">
</div>

<div class="box e" id="E">
<img src="http://via.placeholder.com/170x100">
</div>

<div class="box f" id="F">
<img src="http://via.placeholder.com/170x100">
</div>

<!-- - -- - - - - - - - - -->

</body>
```

Comment: Just curious, why use `not()` in your `@supports` rule? You could make the table layout the default, and instead test for grid support.

Comment: Not really an answer, but I would suggest wrapping your grid CSS inside of an `@supports` and put it below the table-based layout code. The simple reason is that there are likely more browsers that support `@supports` *and* grid than support `@supports` and not grid.

Comment: I tried out the other way, but then the table layout is dominant and grid isn't working...

Comment: @tiffsen What browser is not working? Typically you put the layout in and then put the progressive enhancement (the grid layout, in this case) in the `@supports` declaration, like sol mentioned. The reason you do this is because the browser that might not support grid layout might also not support feature queries like `@supports` yet... which is probably your problem, like Mike hinted at. But we can't know for sure until you tell us which browser is having the problem.

Comment: (And for reference, IE11 does not and therefore will never support feature queries like `@supports`)

Comment: thanks for mentioning that. I guess IE users got to live with the fallback then ;-) I really wondering about grid was invented so late, cause it is so much better than layouttechniques with the help of floats or tables...